# Casting an object in an Array vs ArrayList and calling methods on the object

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, static, polymorphism

```
java.util.ArrayList<car> cList = new java.util.ArrayList<Car>();

car[] cArray = new car[20];
```

Lets say I have a Toyota class that extends Car class. Car class has a print method that is overridden in the Toyota class.

I know if I create Toyota objects then place them in the cArray they will become Car objects, and if I wanted to call a `print(Toyota t)` function on them I would need to cast the object at the print() method call like this: (would this be upcasting or downcasting?)

assuming cArray has Toyota objects in the first 10 indices

```
Toyota toy = (Toyota)cArray[0];
toy.print(toy); //this should call the Toyota's print method
```

Would this be possible if I were to use an ArrayList?

```
Toyota toy = (Toyota)cList.get(0);
toy.print(toy); //does this call Toyota's print method or car's print method?
```

A final note: I'm am unsure if `toy.print(toy)` is the proper way to go about this, I've read through textbooks and javadocs etc. but I haven't seen an object.method(exactSameObject) used before. In my Main, where I need to be calling this, I use `Car.print(toy)` however the compiler states this cannot be referenced from a static context. Clearly I'm not understanding some fundamental concepts, please help!

Comment: _they will become Car objects_ No, they are already `Car` objects.

Comment: +1, that is a _crucial_ part of OO to understand. There's a difference between the runtime type of an object and the compile-time type of a _reference_ by which that object is known. If you do `Car car = new Toyota()`, the `car` reference has a type of `Car`, but this does not modify the `new Toyota()` object in _any_ way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, once it's a `Toyota` object, it's already a `Car` object.  Just because there is a `Car` reference doesn't mean that the `Toyota` isn't a `Toyota` anymore.  There is no need to cast to a `Toyota` to call `Toyota`'s `print` method, because you've said `Toyota`'s `print` method overrides that of `Car`.  Polymorphism in Java ensures that if you have a superclass (`Car`) reference to a subclass (`Toyota`) that overrides a method, then the subclass method is called, not the superclass method.  This should work fine:

```
Car car = cList.get(0);
car.print(car);
```

or the array version:

```
Car car = cArray[0];
car.print(car);
```

Also, passing the instance in a method to itself probably isn't necessary.  You should be able to remove that parameter from the method (in both classes) and just call:

```
car.print();
```

Also, `Car.print(car);` is what you'd type if the `print` method were `static`.  That method is not `static`, because you've said it's overridden (static methods aren't overridden).

Answer (score 2):

```
Toyota toy = (Toyota)cArray[0];
toy.print(toy); //this should call the Toyota's print method
```

Indeed, this would call the Toyota's print method, but, is that really what you want?

If you override the toString() method in Toyota, you can do this:

```
System.out.println( toy );
```

The overridden method would look something like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return "I'm a Toyota!";
}
```

Now no casting is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If Toyota is a subclass of Car, then you don't really need to do all of this.

```
public class Car {
   public void print() {
       System.out.println("I am a car");
   }
}

public class Toyota extends Car {
   public void print() {
       System.out.println("I am a Toyota car");
   }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
   car[] cArray = new car[20];
   car[0] = new Car();
   car[1] = new Toyota();

   car[0].print();
   car[1].print();
}
```

should output

I am a car

I am a Toyota car

Both objects are Cars.